# Why var is required while overriding abstract field of trait?

Tags: scala, traits

I am reading about traits and I got confused about one thing.

```
trait PizzaTrait {
  var toppings: Int
  var size  = 14
  var maxToppings = 14
}

class Pizza extends PizzaTrait{
  var toppings = 0 // need to use var keyword here
  size = 16        // not required
}
```

Why do i have to use `var` before `toppings`? Won't it create new variable toppings with same name?

According to my understanding, it is not overriding toppings and creating a new variable. If I don't use var before it, the compiler signals me the following error.

```
error: class Pizza needs to be abstract, since variable toppings in trait Pizza of type Int is not defined
```

Comment: In scala, `var` is discouraged, even more as public members

Comment: I know that, i am curious about why it behaves so ?

Comment: `toppings` is abstract. `size` is not. Therefore a derived `class` will inherit `size` but `toppings` doesn't exist until the derived `class` creates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define

```
var toppings: Int
```

without any kind of assignment you are telling the compiler that whoever wishes to extend this definition must have its own definition of `toppings`. If you have experience with Java, it's the same as defining the field as `abstract`.

If your intention is to actually provide a concrete implementation in the parent class, you'd have to explicitly assign a value to it, even a *default* one:

```
var toppings: Int = _
```

Without putting the `var` keyword before the name, you are trying to access something which is not defined on the class you are writing, whereas abstract members need to be defined first.

Please note that the content of this answer actually applies to all fields, be them `var`s, `val`s or `lazy val`s.

Answer (score 2):

Because `toppings` in `PizzaTrait` is not initialized (and, therefore, is abstract).

Either initialize it in some way:

```
var toppings: Int = _
var toppings: Int = 0
```

Or implement it in a class that inherits `PizzaTrait`, as you do in 
 class `Pizza`.

Comment: Please add solution details in your answer